# iOS Storyboard Loose Connection?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, storyboard, viewcontroller

I have a very simple application that has only 2 view controllers. The initial root controller has two UIButtons on it, and they both transition to the 2nd view controller via Storyboard. The information that is loaded on the 2nd view controller is determined by a buttonPressed IBAction that is linked to both the initial view controller. The problem I am having is that once I tap one of the two buttons, I get the 2nd view controller loading up blank. From debugging, I notice that the buttonPressed function is called after the 2nd view is loaded. How can I make it so that the buttonPressed function is called BEFORE the 2nd view controller is loaded blank?

Hardly any code involved, I have both UIButtons tagged 1 and 2, and the button press function loads two text files depending on the sender tag equaling 1 or 2. Everything is linked up in Storyboard. Any suggestions?

*buttonPressed function:

if([sender tag] == 1)

```
count = 1;
```

else

```
count = 2;
```

The count determines the file to be loaded.

*In Storyboard, I have just 2 view controllers, (No navigation or any of that) and two UIButtons on the initial view and a text view on the second to display text. The UIButtons are connected to buttonPressed and to the 2nd view controller segue.

Comment: Can you show the code for your buttonaction? Also, are you using segues to switch viewcontrollers? Do you have a UINavigationController?

Comment: I edited it, hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: Does each button have its own segue or are you using the same segue for both?

Comment: Separate segue for both buttons, but they are to the same place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a case for `prepareForSegue`!

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"First Button Segue Identifier"])
    {
        ViewController *theViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        theViewController.textProperty = self.firstButtonText;
    } 
    else if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"Second Button Segue Identifier"])
    {
        ViewController *theViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        theViewController.textProperty = self.secondButtonText;
    }
}
```

There you go, it is pretty generic because I didn't know your variable names or what text you are using.  Similarly, if the segues don't have seperate identifiers, you can use the sender to determine which button is being pressed.

Good luck!

Comment: Could I implement the viewController in storyboard first and set the destination programatically in prepareForSegue?

Comment: no, the destination is set in the storyboard.  The UIStoryboardSegue has a property for "destinationViewController" which points to the view controller that you link to in your storyboard.  So what we are doing here is snatching that viewController from the segue's property and assigning properties of that view with whatever information we want.   You will need to replace `ViewController` with whatever you called your second view controller class, and `textProperty` with whatever property you are using to determine what text to display.

Comment: if I override the prepareForSegue fuction, will I have to manage every segue in the entire project from now on?

Comment: No you are not managing the segue.  This function does nothing until you make it do something.  The segue will transition on its own, this just lets you pause before the segue and "prepare" for the transition.  The segue will still happen no matter what.  You can have 15 different segues and only catch two of them in this function and actually do something and the other 13 will just keep trucking along like nothing happened.

Comment: it worked! All I did was add my buttonPressed code to prepareForSegue. Not very efficient but it worked. Thanks for your help.

Comment: That's all you needed to do ;)   See buttonPressed uses the same sender as prepareForSegue, so if you are using the sender in buttonPressed to do your work then the same code should work in prepareForSegue...should have said that from the beginning I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother with a IBAction for button pressed.  Have the buttons segue to the new controller and use `prepareForSegue:sender:` to figure out which button was tapped (the sender).

You can then get a reference to your controller that's about to appear with something like...

```
SecondController *next = (SecondController *)[segue destinationViewController];
```

...and tell it which file to load, which it can do in `viewDidLoad:`.

Comment: How is this a better solution than an IBAction?

Comment: It's doesn't depend on the order of things being called and it takes advantage of the fact that you're using a storyboard.

Comment: Well why would the order be wrong here? Why wouldn't the buttonPressed function be called immediately and then the view loaded?

Comment: I'm not sure that it's wrong because I don't know anywhere that they define which is going to happen first.  For example, I know that if the segue is from a table cell, the order is not what I would have expected.

Comment: Well this is a test app that I made for my larger one. The buttonPressed loads immediately after pressed, then loads the information on another view. It works for 3 out of 5 buttons, yet the other 2 have the same issue I've described above.